# encoded text of secretkey from keystore is null in android M

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to implement 256 bit AES encryption, I refer this- http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2015/06/keystore-redesign-in-android-m.html
The KeyGenerator looks like this .

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
                    .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,"AndroidKeyStore");
            KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
                     KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)  

                     .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5 *11160)
                     .build();
            keyGenerator.init(spec);
            SecretKey key1 =   keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

When I import encoded value of the key from keystore, it returns null to me.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
               keyStore.load(null); 
SecretKey key3 = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
Log.d("Test MM",key3.getEncoded()+",");
```

I found null value of key3.getEncoded() in logcat.Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symmetric keys generated in the keystore are unexportable in Android M. So it works exactly as it is supposed to. You can still use the key with a `Cipher` to encrypt/decrypt, but you cannot get the raw key bytes. Generally you should need to either.

Comment: Thankyou very much Nikolay, I tried it, Cipher encrypted that key successfully but when I tried to decrypt that cipher text using that secret key, it gives throws me an exception when i call init on cipher in decrypt mode - 'trying to get lenght of null array'. Please post your code if you tried, it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Just follow the example in the platform docs. You need to use a `Cipher` object backed by Android's OpenSSL provider for this to work. Any other provider (including Bouncy Castle) will try to use the raw key bytes, and fail. Also, since this is SO, you should post your full code, so that people have a chance to point out any mistakes you've made.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. I have found updated andorid-keystore library for andorid m here - https://github.com/elouet/android-keystore/tree/android_m_update. download and implement in my project. That's all I need.